# Align footnote in htmlTable in R

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

I am trying to create a table using `htmlTable` package in `R` and I find it difficult to align the footnote to the left bottom bottom of the table.

Below is the relevant code:

```
library(htmlTable)

# Create a sample matrix
output <-  matrix(rep(paste("xx (xx.x)"),times = 36), 
                  ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)

# Generate htmlTable outputs
tblOutput <- htmlTable(output,
                       header       =  c("Group A", "Group B", "Goup C"),
                       rnames       = paste0("Row name", 1:12),
                       css.rgroup   = "text-align: left; font-weight: 10;",
                       css.cgroup   = "line-height: 2px;",
                       css.tspanner = "font-weight: 10; text-align: left;",
                       caption      = "Title name",
                       tfoot        = "- Details about row name 1")

# Return table in html format
htmlTableWidget(tblOutput,number_of_entries = 10)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that if `tfoot = "- Details about row name 1"` is replaced by the following:

```
"<div align='left'> Information about row name 1 </div>
```

It will actually work perfect.

Thanks!